# Order element with a for..in and each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I tried to figure out how I can order items, inside a for..in loop, inside another each loop, looping through my order's array to respect.

I have an object with my data :

```
dataObj = {
    "sites":{
        "dribbble":{
            // ID = 0
            "username":"JeremDsgn"
        },
        "behance":{
            // ID = 1
            "username":"JeremDsgn"
        },
        "cinqcentpx":{
            // ID = 2
            "username":"jeremdsgn"
        }
    },
    "order":["1","2","0"]
};
```

Actually I add the id for each items in the display loop, but can it be better to add the `id` in the object ?

So after, I tried to display my items with the order's array to respect.

```
var index = 0;

for (var site in dataObj.sites) {
    var itemList = '<li id="' + index + '">' + site + '</li>';

    $.each(dataObj.order, function(i, id) {
        console.log(i, id);
        $(itemList).appendTo('.list-social .social-wrapper');       
    });

    index++;
}
```

But I duplicate my site 3 times, because, at this time I have 3 elements on my dataObj.sites object.

So how can I do to display my itemList with the good order? The final result should be :

```
<div class="list-social">
    <ul class="social-wrapper">
        <li id="1">behance</li>
        <li id="2">cinqcentpx</li>
        <li id="0">dribbble</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/JeremDsgn/XhnyS/**

Comment: It's the `for-in` statement that's at issue. That's the part that doesn't guarantee the order. Instead use a `for` statement (or `$.each`) to iterate the `dataObj.order` Array, but instead of giving it indices, give it the name of each `dataObj.sites` property in the order you want to visit it.

Comment: ... `order:["behance","cinqcentpx","dribbble"]` and then you'll want to add the ID to each object too.

Comment: It's isn't clear at all for me. Because actually I already loop through dataObj.order with a each loop.

Comment: ...if the IDs are really meant to correspond to a zero-based index of each object, then an Array of Objects would seem to make much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive what you are trying to do, but maybe this fiddle helps?
http://jsfiddle.net/XhnyS/7/

Instead of using indexes and order list of stringed numbers, I simply changed the order list to the site keys themselves, then created one list item and added it to every .social-wrapper found.

```
dataObj = {
    "sites":{
        "dribbble":{
            "username":"JeremDsgn"
        },
        "behance":{
            "username":"JeremDsgn"
        },
        "cinqcentpx":{
            "username":"jeremdsgn"
        }
    },
    "order":["cinqcentpx", "behance", "dribbble"]
};

for (var i = 0; i < dataObj.order.length; i++) {
    var siteName = dataObj.order[i];
    var itemList = $('<li/>').attr('id', i).text(siteName + ': ' + dataObj.sites[siteName].username);
    $(itemList).appendTo('.list-social .social-wrapper');
}
```

Edited to actually answer the question :)

Comment: You're not using the `dataObj.order` list. The `Object.keys()` doesn't guarantee any particular order, just like `for-in`.

Comment: I should have only three li item, the other are duplicates and I didn't know how to don't repeat them. And I would rather keep number for order if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked.

```
   $.each(dataObj.order, function(i, id) {
    console.log(i, id);
    var index = 0;  
    for (var site in dataObj.sites) {
       console.log(index);
        if(index==id){
          console.log("equal",id,index,site);
          var itemList = '<li id="' + index + '">' + site + '</li>';
          $(itemList).appendTo('.list-social .social-wrapper');
          break;
          }
    index++;
    }
});
```